# How many bit.ly links can I create per account

Tags: api, bit.ly

I have searched the bitly API documentation for limits, and I only see information about *rate* limits, i.e. the amount of people that can visit your short link in a given period of time (http://dev.bitly.com/rate_limiting.html).

Id like to know if there is a limit to how many short links I can create via the API? a thousand? a million? gazillion?

Comment: "If you're a high-volume user of the bitly API, please contact us at api@bitly.com to discuss your options." I would do that if you're concerned about creating too many.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a support issue, not programming.

Comment: So questions about apis and web services are about support and not programming?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested by Runscope, I contacted api@bitly.com and they responded quickly as follows:

"There's no limit on the number of short links you can create. The rate limits are per-hour and per-minute bursts, but you can keep shortening URLs forever."

Nice.

Comment: How many Number of links we can create as free?